# Script to reassign floating IP address to my other machine running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-scripting, ip-address, digital-ocean

I have a floating IP(X.X.X.191) assigned to the machine (Y.Y.Y.106) currently running ubuntu. Now I want the same floating IP to be assigned to my other droplet(Z.Z.Z.252).

On digital ocean I can do the same from the web app interface. However I need to do the same programmatically.

How can I do the same on ubuntu OS?
Is there any command or script to do it?

Comment: Have you had a look at [the API documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/post_floating_ip_action)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.